# Delete duplicate rows from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have unique keys id keys in my table but I have a column with duplicate values? how do I get rid of those, while preserving only one of them like this :

Duplicate records :

```
id  | name   | surname |
1   | test   | one     |
2   | test   | two     |
3   | test3  | three   |
4   | test7  | four    |
5   | test   | five    |
6   | test11 | eleven  |
```

Without duplicates :

```
id  | name   | surname |
1   | test   | one     |
3   | test3  | three   |
4   | test7  | four    |
6   | test11 | eleven  |
```

I've googled this but it seems not to be working :

```
DELETE  ct1
FROM    mytable ct1
        , mytable ct2
WHERE   ct1.name = ct2.name 
        AND ct1.id < ct2.id 

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ct1"
LINE 1: DELETE  ct1
                ^

********** Error **********
```

I'm using postgres database.

Comment: After you get that data cleaned up, you probably need to put a UNIQUE constraint on "name".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this running **multiple times**:

```
delete from mytable where id in (
    select max(id)
      from mytable
     group by name
    having count(1) > 1
);
```

Where **multiple times** equals the maximum number of repetitions you have in `name` column.

Otherwise, you can try this more complex query:

```
delete from mytable where id in (
    select id from mytable
    except 
    (
    select min(id)
      from mytable
     group by name
    having count(1) > 1
    union all
    select min(id)
      from mytable
     group by name
    having count(1) = 1
    )
);
```

Running this query one time only should delete all you need. Haven't tried it though...

Comment: Glad it helped. For complex grouping like this, I would recommend you to learn `window functions` such as `Rank` @Dalen is suggesting in other answer. They're worth learning.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Rank](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html), actually I'm not totally sure about the syntax because I'm not that good at PostgreSQL, this is just a hint anyway (anybody's correction will be appreciated):

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE id NOT IN
(
   SELECT x.id FROM
   (
      SELECT id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id ASC) AS r
      FROM mytable
   ) x
   WHERE x.r = 1
)
```