# How to delete only duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

How I can create an SQL command to delete all rows from table where I have two or more specific columns with the same value and still I don't lose that row, only the duplicates?

For example:

```
Id      value1     value2
1          71            5
2          8             8
3          8             8
4          8             8
5          23           26
```

Id2, Id3 and Id4 have same `value1` and `value2`.

I need to delete all duplicate rows like  (Id3 and Id4)  or (Id2 and Id4)  or (Id2 and Id3)

Comment: So many duplicates in the "related" column

Comment: Duplicate? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921167/delete-duplicate-rows-from-table/5921258#5921258

Comment: use distinct(value1),distinct(value2) in your table

Comment: I thought distinct worked on a column level. Not a field level. As the Ids differ, Distinct wont work?

Answer (score 2):

```
delete t
from table1 t
inner join table1 t2
on t.id>t2.id and t.value1=t2.value1 and t.value2=t2.value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL allows ungrouped fields in queries:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ids AS
  (SELECT id
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY value1, value2);

DELETE FROM your_table
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is copy the distinct records into a new table by:

```
select distinct * into NewTable from MyTable
```