# Unique Index with counter and delete

Tags: postgresql, indexing, duplicates, unique, sql-delete

I have a table with three columns.
I want to create a `unique index` about all three columns with a counter, which tells me, where the duplicates are. I also want to delete them.

Comment: CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer,
    name_no integer,
    price integer
);
INSERT INTO products (product_no, name_no, price) VALUES
    (1, 3, 99),
    (2, 5, 199),
    (3, 6, 299),
    (3, 3, 1);
select * from products;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name on products(product_no, name_no, price);
and I get no error but I have duplicates or?

Comment: Well: if you have a unique index, you cannot have duplicates. And if you have duplicates, you cannot have a unique index.

Comment: I want to delete all duplicate values
And where they are in the table

Comment: There are two records with product_no = 3. And there are two records with name_no=3. Which one would you call a duplicate ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777633/delete-duplicate-rows-dont-delete-all-duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921167/delete-duplicate-rows-from-table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669366/find-duplicate-rows-and-keep-the-latest-one-delete-the-rest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243567/remove-duplicate-from-a-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem really is, but if you need to delete duplicates in your postgre database try this:

```
DELETE FROM tablename 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id
          FROM (SELECT id,
                         row_number() over (partition BY column1, column2, column3 ORDER BY id) AS rnum
                 FROM tablename) t
          WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

"Sometimes a timestamp field is used instead of an ID field."

It helped me to delete duplicates from my tables.

You can find this solutiona at:
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates